# Javascript changing height and width does not change SRC image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, resize, onload

Ok here's what I want to do. I'm going to have the user upload a photo into the dom and resize it client side. I need to change the width of the image before I display the image for the user to interact with it via $.imgAreaSelect. Then I'm going to do other stuff.

But the part that I'm not getting right is the "image.width =" part. When I set the src to an img, after I set the size, the image will remain the same size.

```
var readImage = function(file){

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var image  = new Image();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function(_file) {

        image.src    = _file.target.result;
        image.onload = function() {

            this.width = 1200;

            $('img#photo').attr('src',this.src);

        };
    };
};
```

Here's an example:
http://patomation.com/dev/imagesizer2/

Go ahead and drag and drop a photo into the mouth and you'll see what I mean. The result should be a larger image.

Comment: Have you tried setting the width on `img#photo` instead? And have you tried setting the style rather than the `.width` property? `$('img#photo').css("width", "1200px");`?

Comment: I think your right. I'm trying this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are changing the width of the image reference created on var image , not the img element in html. thats the reason the img in html doent change its width

you should do this i think

```
$('img#photo').attr('width',this.width);
$('img#photo').attr('src',this.src);
```